# TypeError: can’t convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: python

TypeError: can’t convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

learned_pred = euclidean_distances(answer.cpu().data.numpy(), predicates_emb).argmin(axis=1)

The type error is raised in the above line of code I used .cpu() so I cannot understand why..

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from variable **answer** is true. Therefore, I think the problem may stay in the variable **predicates_emb**.

Can you check if var **predicates_emb** is tensor or not. If it is, you should convert it to numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, a `answer.cpu()` did not work for me but `answer.to('cpu')...` did work for me.